# How to know if a page is private or public in Liferay theme?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme

As the tittle says... How to know if a page is private or public? I need to implement some logic in a velocity file from my custom theme only for private pages.

I found this page [Access Objects from Velocity](https://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity#section-Access+Objects+from+Velocity-Objects+Available+in+Themes,+Layouts,+and+CMS) and it seems very useful but I need some help with the API because I don't know which utility class has a method for what I'm looking.

I thought in a workaround making my condition a theme property, but I don't want to depend from the admin user

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Artem Khojoyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2347034/artem-khojoyan)'s answer above is to the point.

But I would like to add some more info.

Page in liferay is represented by `Layout` object. Theme template supports `layout` as well as many more objects in the theme-template, which you can check in the class [`VelocityVariablesImpl`](https://github.com/agmip/liferay-portal-impl/blob/master/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java). You can check statements like `velocityContext.put("key","value");` where `key` is the variable you can use in velocity template as `$key`.

So since `$layout` is nothing but the [`Layout`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/model/impl/LayoutModelImpl.java) object, you can use all the public instance methods of this [`Layout`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/model/impl/LayoutModelImpl.java) object in velocity.

*For every request, `$layout` in theme represents the current-page, which needs to be loaded.*

So finally you can do the following in your `portal_normal.vm` or `init_custom.vm` or any other `*.vm` you have in the theme:

```
#if($layout.isPublicLayout())
  #*.. do something if it is public ...*#
#else
  #*.. do something if it is private ...*#
#end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
#if($layout.isPublicLayout())
  //
#else
  //
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as well :

```
#if($layout.isPublicLayout())
  #*.. This is public ...*#
#elseif ($layoutmodel.isprivatelayout())
  #*.. This is private ...*#
#end
```

for more details about other methodes for Liferay [Interface Layout](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Layout.html)